# Could all iterates of $s(n)=2n+1$ be composite for some starting $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, dynamical-systems

Let $s(n)=2n+1$ and $\sigma(n)=\{n,s(n),s^2(n),s^3(n),\ldots\}$,
where $s^3$ denotes functions composition, $s^3(n)=s(s(s(n)))$.
For example $\sigma(11)=\{11,23,47,95,\ldots\}$.
As another example $\sigma(4)=\{4,9,19,39,\ldots\}$.

Question 1. Is there a positive integer $k$ such that every 
element of $\sigma(2^k)$ is composite?
In other words, is it possible that, starting with $2^k$, all of its iterates under $s$ are composite?

Questions 2. Is there a positive integer $n$ such that every 
element of $\sigma(n)$ is composite?

The above may be lacking motivation, I came up with it while thinking 
of a comment (between Q2 and Q3) in the following [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205911/a-collatz-like-function-that-bifurcates-on-primes), but it is unclear if what I ask would be of any help answering that question ... but I thought I might ask anyway.

For example $s(16)=33$ composite, $s^2(16)=s(33)=67$ prime. So $16$ did not work.

$s(32)=65$ composite, $s(65)=131$ prime, did not work.

If $n=2^{20}=1048576$ then $s^j(n)$ is composite for $j=0,..,7$ but 
$s^8(n)=268435711$ is prime.

$s^j(58)$ is composite for $j=0,\ldots,11$ but 
$s^{12}(58)=241663$ is prime, did not work.

Would it ever work for either some $n$ of the form $2^k$, or for any 
positive integer $n$?
Does the answer follow from known results, any reference?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki: I deleted because I realized I needed $-1$ not $1$, so Riesel rather than Sierpinski, and so needed to find the Riesel link. You were first with a correct answer, there is no reason to delete.

Comment: @AndréNicolas My answer wouldn't have existed if I hadn't read yours; I encourage you to go ahead and undelete your corrected version so that I can upvote it. :-)

Comment: OK, I will undelete.

Answer (score 5):

We answer the second question.

Riesel showed that there are infinitely many natural numbers $k$ such that $k2^n-1$ is composite for all natural numbers $n$. Such numbers $k$ are called [Riesel numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesel_number) The smallest number known to be Riesel is $509203$ but there may be smaller ones.

In your notation, if $k$ is a Riesel number, then all numbers in $\sigma(k-1)$ are composite. For in general $s(k2^m-1)=k2^{m+1}-2+1=k2^{m+1}-1$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, AndréNicolas, thank you both :) I read both your original answers, tried to post a comment (to the first answer by AndréNicolas): "Thank you for your answer, I learned something that I didn't know (about [Sierpinski numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number#Known_Sierpi.C5.84ski_numbers)) and that might be related to my question. But I think there might have been some misunderstanding about what I am asking, I think with $k=78557$, $n=2k=157114$ we get $s^{16}(n)=2513839$, prime." 
Misunderstanding cleared, this answered my Question 2, what about Question 1 :)

Comment: I should have made it clear that I was answering the second question. Have edited to make that clear. I do not have an answer to the first question.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am trying to absorb what I got, it could be I am asking for too much in Question 1, but I learned something with your answer to Question 2.

Comment: You are welcome. Sierpinski numbers would take care of the analogous question where $2n+1$ is replaced by $2n-1$.

Comment: Yes, it is $k-1$, thanks.